# How do I compare two multi-dimensional arrays for unique entries?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have two multi dimensional arrays.  I want to compare them and add unique items to a new array.  I would like to compare each field of the array (year, month, day, time)

Current Array =

```
array(0) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["year"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
    ["month"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["day"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["time"]=>
    string(4) "0900"
  }
 [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["year"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
    ["month"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["day"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["time"]=>
    string(4) "0800"
  }
}
```

Insert Array =

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["year"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
    ["month"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["day"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["time"]=>
    string(4) "0800"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["year"]=>
    string(4) "2015"
    ["month"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["day"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["time"]=>
    string(4) "0800"
  }
}
```

In this case the first item from the insert array would be saved to the new array.  I would like to do this with 100+ items potentially.  The end goal is to not allow duplicate inserts on the table.  Thanks for the input.

Found it:
[Compare two multidimensional arrays then create array of only unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135311/compare-two-multidimensional-arrays-then-create-array-of-only-unique)

Comment: looks like it could be done mostly with mysql

Comment: How so?  is there an insert where statement?

Comment: `INSERT .. WHERE year != .. and month !=..  and day != ..` but  if those are dates in the db, you really should use a proper date\time field

Comment: Let me know if I should submit a new question.  My current query is INSERT INTO `availability_table` (user_id,availability_time) VALUES (?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?),(?,?).  How do I retool this query to make use of the where no?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  function isMatch($input, $database){
         //check if there is a match
       $match = array_diff($input, $database);
        /**Just incase there is a match array_diff returns an empty array
       And when there is no match, it returns an array with keys and values
       Where by in this case will result into false.**/ 
       if($matches == array()):
           return true;
       else:
           return false;
       endif;

 }

  /***using the function
  Suppose this where to cime from the form 
 fetch from the form fields
 if(isset($_POST['send'])):
 $year = $_POST['year'];
 $month = $_POST['month'];
 $day   = $_POST['day'];
 $time = $_POST['time'];

 $input = array('year'  => $year,
              'month' => $month,
              'day'   => $day,
              'time'  => $time
 );
  **************************/


 $input = array('year'  => 2015,
           'month' => 2,
           'day'   => 28,
           'time'  => 2000
);

$database = array('year'  => 2015,
              'month' => 2,
              'day'   => 28,
              'time'  => 2000
);
if(!isMatch($input, $database)):
   echo "okay save the new data";
else:
   echo "Data already in database";
endif;          

?>
```

By changing the value in input array you can see how this function works